# Comparision of Two Dates

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to compare two different dates one current date and other stored in database.

Current Date

```
DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
String Date = CurrentDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Query

```
String query_str = "SELECT * FROM [" + TAdvert_table + "] WHERE ([Country]='China' AND [Viewed] IS NULL) AND ([DateStart]="+Date+")";
```

Exception:

```
{"Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int"}
```

Table Definition

```
Id          int Checked
Title           varchar(50) Checked
Description varchar(MAX)    Checked
ImageLocation   varchar(50) Checked
Country         varchar(50) Checked
City            varchar(50) Checked
NrInQueue   varchar(50) Checked
DateStart   date            Checked
DateEnd         date            Checked
NoOfClicks  int         Checked
Paid            varchar(50) Checked
Viewed          varchar(5)  Checked
```

Comment: First of all this is clear case of SQL Injection, you should use SQL DbParameters.

Answer (score 3):

**The problem:**

After executing following source code:

```
DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
String Date = CurrentDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
String query_str = "SELECT * FROM [" + TAdvert_table + "] WHERE ([Country]='China' AND [Viewed] IS NULL) AND ([DateStart]="+Date+")";
```

the `query` variable could contains this T-SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ([Country]='China' AND [Viewed] IS NULL) AND ([DateStart]=11/05/2014)
```

Following expression: `11/05/2014` is considered as mathematical expression and is evaluated to `0`. In SQL Server Management Studio try:

```
SELECT 11/05/2014 -- > 0
```

Also the result of this expression `11/05/2014` is an INT (not an DECIMAL/NUMERIC/FLOAT/REAL).

Try:

```
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(11/05/2014, 'BaseType') -- > INT
```

This is the reason why this predicate `([DateStart]=11/05/2014)` generates that error `Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int`. Also, you could try:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) = 11/05/2014 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

which generates the same error.

**Solutions:**

1) You could use single quotes (`... '"+Date+"'`):

```
String query_str = "SELECT * FROM [" + TAdvert_table + "] WHERE ([Country]='China' AND [Viewed] IS NULL) AND ([DateStart]='"+Date+"')";
```

Thus, the generated query could be: `SELECT ... ([DateStart]='11/05/2014')`. This could work **or not** depending on current [`DATEFORMAT` setting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx).

Note: I would not use this solution.

2) To avoid the problem caused by different `DATEFORMAT` settings you could use the following ISO 8601 format `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
String Date = CurrentDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
String query_str = "SELECT ... AND ([DateStart]='"+Date+"')";
```

Note: I would not use this solution.

3) A better approach is to use parameterized queries:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ... WHERE ([Country]='China' AND [Viewed] IS NULL) AND ([DateStart]=@pDateStart)", connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@pDateStart", SqlDbType.Date);
command.Parameters["@pDateStart"].Value = CurrentDate;
```

Note: generating SQL queries by concatenating strings (for example: table name) [can be dangerous](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Change end of the query to

```
"([DateStart]='"+Date+"')"
```